# How to make a field as optional in a JPA Entity?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I have Table User in SQL Server DB with close to 30 columns. I have also created an JPA Entity for corresponding DB Table.
The JPA entity looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
@Setter
@Getter
public class User{

@Id
@Column(name="ID",nullable=false)
private Integer id;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="ADDRESS")
private String address;

@Column(name="FATHER_NAME")
private String fathersName;

}
```

Now I am trying to create a native query which will only fetch id and name from the User Table.
The Repository class looks something like this.

```
@Repository
public interface UserDao extends JpaRepository<User,Integer>{

@Query(value=" SELECT u.ID,u.NAME from USER u", nativeQuery=true)
List<User> fetchUser();

}
```

Now when this is being executed, it is throwing an exception as below:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerException: The column name address is not valid
```

When I add the address column to my query this exception goes but then it come for another field.

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SqlServerException: The column name father_name is not valid
```

So, now I want to modify the JPA Entity in such a way that this fields became optional.
I have tried using
**@Transient** but if some other query is using this address field then it will come as null over there.
I have also tried all the below annotations:

- **@Basic**
- **@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)**
- **@Column(nullable="true")**
- **@JsonProperty**

But none of this annotations work for me.

Comment: Make a separate class `UserNameView` that maps onto the same table (and don't include `@Setter`).

Comment: We have done this already and it juts works fine. But lets say I have to write 20 different kind of queries which fetch different columns for same Entity then I will have to create 20 different classes. So I am looking for some way where just by modifying this entity all the queries will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define additional constructor for the `User` entity:

```java
@Entity
@Table(name="USER")
public class User {

   public User(){
   }

   public User(Integer id, String name){
      this.id = id;
      this.name = name;
   }

   // ...
}
```

and then write the following query:

```java
@Query("select new your.package.User(u.id, u.name) from User u")
List<User> fetchUser();
```

Note that this is not native, but jpql query.

Please also note that according to the hibernate [documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-select-clause):

> The projection class must be fully qualified in the entity query, and it must define a matching constructor.
> The class here need not be mapped. It can be a DTO class.
> If it does represent an entity, *the resulting instances are returned in the NEW state (not managed!).*

**EDIT**

You can also try to use [spring data jpa projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections) in the following way:

1. Define an interface:

```java
interface UserIdWithName {

  Integer getId();
  String getName();
}
```

The important thing here is that the properties defined here exactly match properties in the aggregate entity.

2. Use this interface in the query method:

```
@Query("select u from User u")
List<UserIdWithName> fetchUserIdWithName();
```

The query execution engine creates proxy instances of that interface at runtime for each element returned and *forwards calls to the exposed methods to the target object.* Please note that you can not select only some fields in the query here.

Comment: This approach doesnt look maintainable/readable if I have to write 10 different queries for the same entity with different columns to fetch in every query. Then I'll have to create 10 different constructors. Apart from that I also tried using @RequiredArgConstructor from lombok. But that didnt help as well.

Comment: See the updated answer, maybe spring data jpa projections will be more suitable for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
@Query(value=" SELECT u.ID,u.NAME, '' as address, '' as father_name from USER u", nativeQuery=true)
List<User> fetchUser();
```

It will set those fields to empty string.

Comment: If its just few columns I would have done this way but tables with 30 -35 columns this doesnt look feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(User.class)
public interface UserDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getName();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`UserDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, UserDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<UserDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!